# AudioSystem clip doesn't stop playing when clip.stop(); is run

Tags: java, audio, clip

I need to make an audio player that plays a sound clip whenever this subroutine is run. It must also stop the previous sound clip before playing the new one.

The issue I'm having is that the clip is never registered as running. Neither of the two if statements that check to see if it is running are ever used. This means the clip only stops when it is finished, and s they can overlap, and ruin the program.

I would use clip.stop(); in other subroutines, but it will tell me that the 'clip' symbol cannot be found. I don't know how to make it available for other subroutines to use.

The only way I can get clip.stop(); to work in this subroutine is by placing it straight after the clip.start(); line, which stops the clip immediately after starting, so it isn't heard at all.

Below is the subroutine I'm using to play audio clips.

```
public void play(String filename){
    try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        audFile = audDir + filename;
        if (clip.isRunning()){
            System.out.println("Sounds playing 1");
            clip.stop();
        }
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(audFile)));
        clip.start();
        if (clip.isRunning()){
            System.out.println("Sounds playing 2");
            clip.stop();
        }
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here, maybe it'll help or give you a solution track: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833553/how-to-stop-a-music-clip-in-java

Comment: `I would use clip.stop(); in other subroutines, but it will tell me that the 'clip' symbol cannot be found.` Does that mean that your code gives you errors? If so, where exactly?

Answer (score 1):

> I would use clip.stop(); in other subroutines, but it will tell me
>   that the 'clip' symbol cannot be found. I don't know how to make it
>   available for other subroutines to use.

Declare a private Clip field in your class

```
private Clip clip;
```

and set it when you get it from `AudioSystem.getClip()`.

```
/*
 * clip (local variable) is invisible from other methods
 */
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip(); 
this.clip = clip; // `this.clip` is a field, it's visible from other methods
```

Then you can access it from other methods ("subroutines" are class methods in Java).

> The issue I'm having is that the clip is never registered as running.

It is not running when you call `clip.isRunning()`, but are you sure it is *never* running?

You can't assume that `clip.isRunning()` returns `true` right after `clip.start()`. The mechanism being asynchronous, it might help to register a `LineListener` and listen to the `START` event.

```
clip.start();
LineListener listener = new LineListener() {
    public void update(LineEvent event) {
    if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.START) {
            /*
             * here you are sure the clip is started
             */
        }
    }
};
clip.addLineListener(listener );
```

Comment: I'm still confused.  Would I use something like `this.clip.start();` / `this.clip.stop();` along with `Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();` and `this.clip = clip;`?

Comment: Yes, you would. (BTW, you don't need to spell `this.clip.start()` and `this.clip.stop()`, just `clip.start()` or `clip.stop()` will do).